# How create an unfinished jump game?

Tags: android, libgdx

i want to create an unfinished jump game. i use super jumper code. the main part for change height of world is :

```
while (y < WORLD_HEIGHT - WORLD_WIDTH / 2) {
    ...
    y += (maxJumpHeight - 0.5f);
    y -= rand.nextFloat() * (maxJumpHeight / 3);
}
```

if i change while condition to a big number(for example 100 or 1000), fps goes low(i get lag).
i try many things. but i couldn't reach to a correct answer.
if someone can, help me.
(sorry for my english...)

Comment: I think "unfinished jump" is a mis-translation of "doodle jump"?  The code you're quoting is the level layout code.  What *specifically* did you change?  And what are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to make the levels "taller"?

Comment: if you mean i want to create a game like doodle jump, i must say "yes". i can make my level taller than this, just change  'y < WORLD_HEIGHT - WORLD_WIDTH / 2' to 'y < WORLD_HEIGHT * 100'. or a number. its simple, but if i change it to a number like 1000, fps goes to a low number. i want to know , how change this number to take tallest height...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
while (y < WORLD_HEIGHT - WORLD_WIDTH / 2) {
```

to

```
while (y < WORLD_HEIGHT * 100) {
```

in Super Jumper's [World.generateLevel](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/demos/superjumper/superjumper/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/World.java#71) will generate a lot more content, but won't actually make the level longer (the display system will only display up to WORLD_HEIGHT, and the end-of-level Castle will still be in the same place.

If you want to make a very large level, change the definition of `WORLD_HEIGHT` itself.  Its currently set to about 20 screens worth of platforms.

The reason the game slows down when you make the levels larger is *probably* because all the per-frame update and collision detection code uses a linear scan of all the elements.  For small levels, this is fine, but if you have very large levels, this won't scale.  However, I'm just guessing, and you should probably run the profiler to figure out where all the time is being spent.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i checked your change, before ask my question. it work well. and about `WORLD_HEIGHT` ,it was 20*15 , now , i change it to 15*200. unfortunately i can't check it on my nexus one. but i just check it on java. it seems work better than when i change while to `while (y < WORLD_HEIGHT * 1000) {` . anyway, thanks a lot.